# Travis ci tests failing but works tests pass when running them locally

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, travis-ci, flask-restful

When i run my tests locally with pytest the test code passes all tests but if i run the code on travis it throws out a 
keyerror :Access token 
Here is my test code.

```
def register_user(self, first_name='Kali', last_name='sir3n',
                  email='user1234@gmail.com', password='testpassword'):
    """Implied registration . A helper method"""
    user_data = {
                'email': email,
                'password': password,
                'First Name': first_name,
                'Last Name': last_name
                }
    return self.client().post('/api-1.0/auth/register', data=user_data)

def login_user(self, email='user1234@gmail.com', password='testpassword'):
    """Implied login. A helper method"""
    user_data = {
                'email': email,
                'password': password,
                }
    return self.client().post('/api-1.0/auth/login', data=user_data)

def test_users_can_create_categories(self):
    """Test if users can create a recipe category(POST)"""
    self.register_user()
    result = self.login_user()
    access_token = json.loads(result.data.decode())['Access token']

# it throws an error on the above basis saying that the access token 
doesnot exist

    res = self.client().post('/api-1.0/categories/', data={
                                                                 "name": "Sweet pie",
                                                                 "detail": "Made by mama"
                                                                 },
                             headers=dict(Authorization="Bearer " + access_token)
                             )
    self.assertEqual(res.status_code, 201)
    self.assertIn('Sweet pie', str(res.data))
```

I have configured my database correctly so it isn't an issue
running the command locally does give me an access token
Testing the api with postman also returns the access token
Any suggestionstions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What is the Travis output? When a test fails, it should tell you which assert has failed.

Comment: it returns an KeyError: Access token @rickdenhaan

Comment: So on Travis, the call to `self.login_user()` fails with a JSON result that does not contain an `Access token` key. So what *does* the JSON result look like? Could it be that the login fails because `self.register_user()` actually fails before that (you're not checking the result of that call)?

Comment: FAIL: test_test (tests.test_api_challenge3.ApiTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/Desktop/Api-challenge-3/tests/test_api_challenge3.py", line 249, in test_test
    self.assertIn('Access token', access_token)
AssertionError: 'Access token' not found in 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJleHAiOjE1MDkzOTAyODcsInN1YiI6MiwiaWF0IjoxNTA5Mzg5OTg3fQ.fskLUcfPX6oiZcAUtCISS9RnUsa0rAiVTJ6FcT1OQy0'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Thanks @rickdenhaan

Comment: Does that mean you figured it out? Because that test case is not part of the code you provided in your question.